# Who were the other riders with Ned Stark at the Tower of Joy?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-identification

In the novel *A Game of Thrones*, Ned Stark has a dream about the events we see in the *Game of Thrones* show on television.

There are seven in the book:

> In the dream his friends rode with him as they did in life. Proud Martyn Cassel, Jory's father, Faithful Theo Wull, Ethan Glover who had been Brandon's squire, Ser Mark Ryswell soft of speech and gentle of heart, the crannogman Howland Reed, Lord Dustin on his great red stallion. - *A Game of Thrones, Chapter 39*

But there are only six in the show:

In the show the battle goes from 7v3 to 6v2. We know two of the six are Ned and Howland.

**Are the names of the remaining four in Ned's party mentioned in the script or anywhere else?**

---

Other Questions in the "Identify this GoT character by Skooba" series

[Who is the second Kingsguard at the Tower of Joy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128500/who-is-the-second-kingsguard-at-the-tower-of-joy)

[Who were the Kingsguard escorting Cersei?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135086/who-were-the-kingsguard-escorting-cersei-season-6-finale)

Comment: I read that as Ned Flanders...

Comment: I honestly can't find anything online... There is a lot of talk about the scene but only in terms of what it means and they never mention who is there other than Ned.

Comment: @Rincewind I used IMDB for the corresponding question about the Kingsguard, but it looks like Ned's companions might have been uncredited...  I'm not finding anything either.

Comment: @kuhl It is like they weren't there at all!

Comment: I doubt there's an answer, but you could make a case if you wanted that Cassel must be the missing man because none of Ned's men here look old enough that they would have a son who'd appear Jory's age in season 1 and to have fought alongside Jaime in Pyke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikia page has been updated since my answer previously, it mentions that those involved are:

- Lord Eddard Stark
- Lord Howland Reed (WIA)
- Ethan Glover
- Lord Martyn Cassel
- Ser Mark Ryswell
- Theo Wull

It's unclear where this is sourced from but if correct it would mean that Willam Dustin was dropped in the show. A quick look into the [revision history](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Showdown_at_the_Tower_of_Joy?action=history) shows it may be sourced from the books and the editor just missed Dustin by mistake so I wouldn't take this as fact at all.

---

## We Do Not Know

I've checked the wikia page on [The Showdown at the Tower of Joy](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Showdown_at_the_Tower_of_Joy) which just refers to the other four as "4 other Northman". I've also checked the [IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4131606/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) for the episode which doesn't include any potential candidates and even lists the young Howland Reed as uncredited.

The Inside the Episode for the scene doesn't mention anything either.

However, of the other five in the books we have:

- Willam Dustin: Head of House Dustin
- Ethan Glover: Former squire to Brandon Stark
- Martyn Cassel: Father of Jory Cassel and brother of Rodrik Cassel
- Theo Wull, of Clan Wull
- Ser Mark Ryswell: a knight of House Ryswell

Of those I'd guess that Willam Dustin, Ethan Glover and Martyn Cassel were there due to the ties to the Starks. Of the other 2 left I'd say it's more possible that Ser Mark Ryswell would have been there over Theo Wull but it's unclear.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the producers decided that the difference between 7 men and 6 men is so small and irrelevant, that they simply decided to cut off one character (which also makes the shooting a bit cheaper).

It is rather clear that, with the exception of Ned and Howland, it doesn't really matter who are those 7 men that rode to the Tower of Joy, for two main reasons:

1. Of the entire band, only 2 (Ned and Howland) were actually important for the plot - GRRM used the Tower of Joy battle as a reason for the Reed's loyalty to the Starks.
2. The fact that only Ned and Howland survived the battle, strengthen a theory in which Lyanna actually had birthed twins - Jon and Meera.

[Link to Meera twin of Jon theory](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/1e361x/spoilers_all_meera_reed_more_than_meets_the_eyes/).

Comment: I am not looking for fan theory or out of universe reasoning.

Comment: First of all, if someone actually answers your question you should be polite, even if you disagree with the answer.
Secondly, as far as I could find (and i did some research in order to answer your question), it was never addressed. Therefore, the only answer I could have given you was what I gave.

Comment: I was merely informing you that this is not the answer I am looking for. I did not ask *why* there were only 6 riders, but *who* they were. If the answer is "We don't know" that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: By "who" do you mean the actor's names? or the characters's names?
it is rather unclear from your question what you are asking? furthermore, the confusing came since you put some emphasis in your question to the fact that in the book there are 7 riders in comparison to the TV series that has 6.

Comment: I am looking for character names, although if you could identify the actors that might be a good way to link them. Yes, I put emphasis on the difference between the books and show because that is where the difference comes in. If the numbers were equal I would know who they are. I am basically trying to find out who was missing and if there might a reason why. However, the *why* part would probably be POB for this site.

Comment: I've been searching far and wide for a more definite answer, but sadly I could not find anywhere who is the rider that is missing. So instead I went and read a bit on each of the companions that are described in the books and I think that they dropped Theo Wull. Theo is a member of the Wull Mountain Clan. In past episodes we've seen how the producers envisioned the Mountain Clans (the ones near the Eagles Nest), and of the entire band there is no one that resembles them. It is true that I might be mistaken and that is not a solid proof that he is the missing rider.Sadly, they were not credited