# Who were the Kingsguard escorting Cersei?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-identification

## This pertains to Season 6 and Season 7 of *Game of Thrones* if you have not caught up this point... Beware the Spoilers!

Now to the question...

---

During the scene where Cersei sits on the Iron Throne and is "sworn in" we see her escorted by seven members of the Kingsguard. Now this is what I would expect as that is the correct number. However, I have *no idea who they are*!

The books pay more attention to detail in this area, but the show is also diverging and outpacing in this regard. We can see that a few of the names are not possible on the show. I have listed the names from the books and given why the reason they could not be members on the show in bold.

- Ser Jaime Lannister, Lord Commander - **Stripped of title**
- Ser Loras Tyrell - **Dead** and also was never a KG on the show.
- Ser Osmund Kettleblack - **Possible, but not mentioned by name**
- Ser Balon Swann - **Possible, but not mentioned by name**
- Ser Meryn Trant - **Dead**
- Ser Boros Blount - **Possible, but not mentioned by name**
- Ser Robert Strong (aka Zombie Mountain) - **Confirmed**

I know it can be confusing mixing the books and shows, but the question still remains the same...

### Who are the current members of the Kingsguard?

Bonus Question: Who is the Lord Commander, if any?

**ETA**: This question can also apply to the Kingsguard escorting her throughout Season 7.

Comment: Why would you even care? The show has never paid much attention to all members of the Kingsguard, and I don't see how knowing their identities would even be relevant.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Clearly ***I*** care or I would not have posted the question...  It could be relevant because the books and shows are shown to leave subtle hints. A characters involved or absence could mean a lot.

Comment: @BCdotWEB  The Kingsguard have played minor but important roles throughout the story (both in the books and TV show). I think it is fair to ask who the current members are protecting Cersei as that could have bearing on future events.

Comment: You completely mixed books and series! Loras Tyrell was never a Kingsguard member in series. Both Meryn and Loras are alive in the books

Comment: @Skooba Books and show are now wildly diverting, especially since the show is now doing non-book material. I challenge to go through all episodes and try to list the members of the Kingsguard at various stages: I bet you won't be able to except for a few key members.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins That is at best speculation and thus opinion-based and thus off-topic. Moreover, the character clean-up that happened in S6 combined with the fact that there's only thirteen episodes to go, is evidence enough that their identity isn't relevant, except for a few of them.

Comment: @BCdotWEB if the answer is "We don't know" that is the answer. It does not make this opinion based.

Comment: Look at the GoT wiki entry on Osmund Kettleblack: ["a background character in the fifth season. He is played by an unidentified extra"](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Osmund_Kettleblack). In what way is knowing his "identity" relevant at all? Is he even imprisoned by the Faith in the show?

Comment: Irrelevance of the identity does not matter. The Question is valid on all counts. Just because it is unanswerable does not mean it is invalid or a bad question. It's a pretty good question which highlights gross negligence that show runners have shown in regard to this very important military order.

Comment: @Aegon How is this a "good question" when the poster can't even get the facts straight and mixes book events into his question? "Gross negligence"? I'm a massive critic of the show, but even a more perfect version could not have spent hours on fleshing out all Kingsguard characters. Not unless they made 20 eps each year -- and even then...

Comment: @BCdotWEB the question remain the same.  i was just trying to provide some context on my line of thinking.  Don't take your frustration for D&D out on me :-P

Comment: @BCdotWEB The inaccuracies were already pointed out and rectified by the time I made that comment. They could just have Joffrey read out current members names from the White Book when he was reading pages about Jaime and Ser Duncan the tall. KG should have had greater part to play. As of now, they are nothing except glorified guards.

Comment: The show has limited time and resources but Kingsguard are supposed to be an integral part of a Monarch's life. Their lord commander has a seat on Small council.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct on many of those accounts:

### Current members

**Ser [Robert Strong](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Gregor_Clegane)**

- This one's obvious

**Ser [Preston Greenfield](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Preston_Greenfield)**

- Not often mentioned, however he was one of the members escorting King Tommen at the Standoff at the Great Sept of Baelor event
- It is presumed that he is still one of the members

**Ser [Balon Swann](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Balon_Swann)**

- Not often mentioned, however he appears next to the Kingsguard who receive Tywin Lannister's arrival and mention that Ser Mandon Moore's position has been filled (after Mandon's death)
- A renown and respected member, yet aged, member in the books
- Presumed to still be a member

**Ser [Osmund Kettleblack](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Osmund_Kettleblack)**

- Not often mentioned
- Presumed to be a member due to his membership in the books

**Ser [Arys Oakheart](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Arys_Oakheart)**

- Not actually named in the show, however he is named in the books

  - Presumed to be the one who escorts Myrcella to Dorne (as in the books)
  - Although he has died in the books, the events of the show haven't transpired the same way, so it's safe to assume he is one of the current members

**Ser [Boros Blount](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Boros_Blount)**

- One of the original members from King Robert I Baratheon's time
- He was one of the assholes who helped Joffrey beat Sansa
- Presumed to still be a member

**Ser 'Unknown Knight'**

- This seventh position is filled by an unnamed knight

Unfortunately, the current Lord Commander is not named.

---

### Previous members

**Ser [Meryn Trant](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Meryn_Trant)**

- Season 5
- Was killed in Braavos by Arya in the "Too old" scene (Season 5, Episode 10: *[Mother's Mercy](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mother%27s_Mercy)*)

  - Replaced by Ser Robert Strong

**Ser [Jaime Lannister](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jaime_Lannister)**

- Formerly Lord Commander
- Dismissed by King Tommen I Baratheon in the aftermath of the '[Standoff at the Great Sept of Baelor](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Standoff_at_the_Great_Sept_of_Baelor#Aftermath)'
- Replaced by an 'unknown knight'

Comment: Was Boros ever "the belly" on show?

Comment: @Skooba I don't recall, or care to recall, sorry. :) I'd say not though.

Answer (score -1):

We wont know until season 7 or more leaks but presumably as Queen she can undismiss Jaime

> And from the leaks seen he is ok with her killing the High Sparrow

Bronn has served them well and could be suggested by Jaime which would give her at least two good fighters (Zombie Mountain and Bronn). And only leaves one spot empty. I'm sure they can find one person willing and able to fill the spot.