# Who are the Kingsguard with Cersei in S8E05?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Assuming [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135086/who-were-the-kingsguard-escorting-cersei?answertab=votes#tab-top) list of candidates is still accurate: who are the two Kingsguard / Queensguard accompanying Cersei and Ser Robert Strong through the Red Keep when they

> encounter the Hound, and get run through in short order,

in S8E05?

Edit: This question is about an entirely different season and episode than the [linked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135086/who-were-the-kingsguard-escorting-cersei?answertab=votes#tab-top) reference, which names 6 of the 7 guards *at that time*, and so is not a duplicate.  I'm asking about who is left *now*; specifically, who are the 2 in this scene.  If it is known.

Comment: In the show the names aren’t actually known, that answer draws from the books if I remember correctly. Therefore they’re just red shirts. Can’t remember exactly though and don’t have time to double check right now.

Comment: They are no-one.

Comment: I've voted to leave closed the current known members are the same known members from the duplicate and as the Queensguard is treated as Red Shirts now we never find out who is who therefore the answer is the same.